# Retrieve the amount of free memory available on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

Is there any way to obtain the available memory (RAM) programatically in iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct way you can access that data using the iPhone SDK. However there are some workarounds...

[This](http://developers.enormego.com/view/iphone_sdk_available_memory) should help answer your question. It's a category based on UIDevice which gives you the amount of free memory available

Alternatively, [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/01/get-the-amount-of-free-memory-available/) post on the getting the amount of free memory with a Code Sample should also help